# Novel where a pregnant woman carrying a manipulated zygote is spirited away

Tags: story-identification, novel, cyborg, genetics

I think the opening takes place in a lab manipulating a zygote; not sure if in vitro or vivo. Krebs cycle is mentioned. A woman carrying the embryo is spirited away. The elite class of maybe immortals searches for her. At one point an underground organization of cyborgs come to her rescue. Buildings are made of materials that regenerate, maybe three times. Maybe 1960s.

Comment: I recommend visiting [this topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) where we have a list of prompts that might give you additional details to [edit] in. Like, was the 1960s when you thought you read it? Or when it was written?

Comment: @WPaDive - If anyone correctly identifies the novel you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 9):

***[The Eyes of Heisenberg](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2015.The_Eyes_of_Heisenberg)*** (1966) by Frank Herbert...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Eyes_of_Heisenberg):

> *The Eyes of Heisenberg* is a 1966 science fiction novel by American writer Frank Herbert. Originally serialized as *Heisenberg's Eyes* in *Galaxy* magazine between June and August 1966, it was issued by Berkley in the same year. The title refers to Werner Heisenberg's uncertainty principle, here applied both on the molecular (genetic) level (producing the atypical embryo the story hinges on) and on a macroscopic, societal level.

From a [review](https://sciencefictionruminations.com/2013/01/19/book-review-the-eyes-of-heisenberg-frank-herbert-1966/):

> *The Eyes of Heisenberg* (1966) is a disturbing far future vision where humans (“Folk”) are the mere pawns of two far greater powers:  the Optimen — genetically superior humans able to live thousands of years — and the Cyborgs, an underground movement that extends the lifespan of the normal human by adding computers, mechanical limps, and even strange weapons that emerge as devastating protrusions from the chests of their wearers.

From a Goodreads [user review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/2556012434?book_show_action=true&from_review_page=1):

> The story starts with some lab preparing to process a zygote for a couple who were lucky enough to be chosen for having a baby. The zygote is examined by the doctor and he sees some unexpected change happen that makes this little one special, even more special than the immortals. He and the technician silently agree to keep the knowledge secret so the zygote will be allowed to grow up.